# Effects with Cleanup - cancels pending API calls in cleanup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

**React album app:**
The task is to build a React app to view the albums owned by users. It should contain a list of users on the left. On the right it should have a list of albums owned by the selected user. As you click through the users, the list of albums should change.

**Errors:**

```
        * cancels pending API calls in cleanup => Calling API with userId=undefined
    
        *  Displays a list albums when user is selected => Expected: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=2", ObjectContaining {"signal": Any<Object>},  Received
          3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=undefined", {"signal": {}}
          4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {"signal": {}}

          Number of calls: 4

          Calling API with userId=undefined
```

```
// App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AlbumList from "./AlbumList";
import UserList from "./UserList";
function App() {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [user, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
  document.title = 'Awesome Album App';

  const userUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  // Loading Albums
  useEffect(() => {
    const albumUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=${user.id}`;
    async function loadAlbums() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(albumUrl, { signal: controller.signal });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log("Logging json: ", json)
        setAlbums(json)
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Aborted', err)
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
    loadAlbums();
    console.log("After loadAlbums: ", albums)
    
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
      document.title = "";
    }
  },[user.id])
  
  // Loading Users
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUser() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(userUrl, { signal: controller.signal });
        const data = await response.json();
        setUsers(...users, data);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Aborted', err)
          setUsers([])
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
    loadUser();
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    }
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="left column">
      <UserList users={users} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} />
      </div>
      <div className="right column">
        <AlbumList user={user} albums={albums} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

// AlbumList.js

import React from "react";

function AlbumList({ user = {}, albums }) {
  console.log("albumList", albums)
  
  if(albums.length&& user){   
    
    return  albums.map((album, index)=>{
    return <p key={index}>{album.id} - {album.title}</p>
    });  
  }

  return  <p>Please click on a user name to the left</p>

}

export default AlbumList;


// UserList.js

import React from "react";

function UserList({ users, setCurrentUser }) {

  return (
    <ul className="user-list">
      {users.map((user) => (
        <p key={user.id}>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentUser(user)}>
            {user.name}
          </button>
        </p>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default UserList;
```

Specific instructions
Load users from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users.
Load albums from [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=${user.id}](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=$%7Buser.id%7D).
Create additional components that are then used by the App component.
Style the components using inline styling and/or CSS files. It does not need to match the appearance of the example image, but should have a reasonable layout.
The document title should be "Awesome Album App" and should reset to the original document title when the component is cleaned up. You can get the original title by accessing document.title and storing that value.
Pending API calls should be canceled when the user changes.
State should be "lifted up" whenever possible.
Do not make any assumptions about the number of users or number of albums owned by the user.
If no user is selected, the right side should display "Please click on a user name to the left"
List of albums should include the album ID and the album title

Comment: I see that your user object is empty. so user.id must be undefined. ergo you can't make a successful call. Or is there a piece of code that actually sets the user info?
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=5 I ran this in the browser and it retrieves some data. So this means that user.id variable is the problematic part in your code

Comment: Your code looks good but I couldn't see anywhere where you get user info

Comment: I get the user info from userUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users".

Answer (score 0):

I made this on codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-browser-w8c9p?file=/src/App.js:0-1142
and it renders a list

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  document.title = "Awesome Album App";
  console.log(users, "1");

  const userUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  // Loading Users
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUser() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(userUrl, { signal: controller.signal });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setUsers([...users, ...data]);
        console.log(users);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === "AbortError") {
          console.log("Aborted", err);
          setUsers([]);
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }

    loadUser();
  }, []);
  console.log(users, "body");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            <li>{user.name}</li>
            <li>{user.username}</li>
            <li>{user.id}</li>
            <li>{user.phone}</li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it is not fix of everything but just to see a working component. I think the reason why you got the error because when you are making the api call although we have no user detail. userId undefined ergo, cant make the call correctly.

I suggest you move loadusers function above loadalbum function. Because order matters when we are running the code.

Comment: I moved the loadUser function above the loadAlbum function and I got the same error:  cancels pending API calls in cleanup => Calling API with userId=undefined

Comment: I'll try to look at it tonight to see what we can do

Answer (score 0):

```
//App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AlbumList from "./AlbumList";
import UserList from "./UserList";

function App() {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [user, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
  document.title = 'Awesome Album App';

  const usersUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  // Loading Users
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUsers() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(usersUrl, { signal: controller.signal });
        const data = await response.json();
        setUsers(...users, data);
      } 
      catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Aborted', err)
          setUsers([])
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
    loadUsers();

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    }
  },[]);

  // Loading Albums
  useEffect(() => {
    const albumUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=${user.id}`;
    async function loadAlbums() {

      if(user.id){
        try {
          const response = await fetch(albumUrl, { signal: controller.signal });
          const json = await response.json();
          console.log("Logging json: ", json)
          setAlbums(json)
        } 
        catch (err) {
          if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
            console.log('Aborted', err)
          } else {
            throw err;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    loadAlbums();
    console.log("After loadAlbums: ", albums)
    
    return () => {
      setAlbums([])
      controller.abort();
      document.title = "";
    }
  },[user]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="left column">
        <UserList users={users} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} />
      </div>
      <div className="right column">
        {(albums.length&&user)? <h3>{user.name} Albums</h3> : <h3></h3>}
        <AlbumList user={user} albums={albums} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
// AlbumList.js

import React from "react";

function AlbumList({ user = {}, albums }) {
  console.log("albumList", albums)
  
  if(albums.length&& user){   
    
    return  albums.map((album, index)=>{
    return <p key={index}>{album.id} - {album.title}</p>
    });  
  }

  return  <p>Please click on a user name to the left</p>

}

export default AlbumList;

// UserList.js

import React from "react";

function UserList({ users, setCurrentUser }) {

  return (
    <ul className="user-list">
      {users.map((user) => (
        <p key={user.id}>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentUser(user)}>
            {user.name}
          </button>
        </p>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: This is the right code. Thank you for helping me.